# Superclass mismatch for class MultiBox (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I'm trying to update a Ruby/Rails app to Rails 4.2. After updating gems, I get a `superclass mismatch for class MultiBox` error. There's no local definition of class `MultiBox` in the code. It's a single code base (no git merge issues). This happens locally on my machine, though it's a heroku-deployed app, which is where the other situations occurred. I get the same error with an older version of prawn-layout (0.7.2).  I appreciate any ideas here.

```
$ rails server
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/prawn-layout-0.8.4/lib/prawn/layout/grid.rb:191:in `<class:Document>': superclass mismatch for class MultiBox (TypeError)
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/prawn-layout-0.8.4/lib/prawn/layout/grid.rb:2:in `<module:Prawn>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/prawn-layout-0.8.4/lib/prawn/layout/grid.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/prawn-layout-0.8.4/lib/prawn/layout.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `rescue in block in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
    from /home/paul/cvtg/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend found the answer: the prawn-layout gem is now deprecated, and its functionality has been consolidated into the prawn gem.  Since our Gemfile was requiring both gems, we got the 'superclass mismatch for class MultiBox' error.  Removing the gem declaration for prawn-layout eliminates the error.